# Can I re-use the SOLR instance that comes with Tridion?

Tags: c#, solr, content-management-system, search-engine, tridion

I have a new built Tridion project that is to use SOLR as its search engine. Does Tridion have its own internal SOLR with its own API? Or should I use the SOLRSharp API pointing to an external instance of SOLR?

[Update]
As a Front End developer, it will be the CD I am concentrating on. It looks like I will be using a separate SOLR instance running Nutch to crawl the published site.

Comment: We recently indexed our broker database with Solr it works great. I will write a blog once we release the project and get some free time. If you are familiar with Tridion and Solr its actually not that complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably talking about using SOLR as the search engine for your web site. Tridion 2011 indeed uses SOLR as the search engine in its Content Management System. But since your web site most likely has completely different search requirements as the Content Management System, there is no value from trying to combine the two search use-cases into a single SOLR instance.